# How to retrieve data from a relationship in Amplify Datastore with Flutter

Tags: flutter, aws-amplify

I can't figure out how to retrieve the data from profile.type.name or profile.langCode.
I can retrieve the data for profile.comment and profile.type.id but not for profile.type.name or profile.langCode.

I'm working with Flutter and AWS Amplify DataStore.

Thanks for your help!

```
return Card(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Text(profile.comment.toString()),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(profile.type.id.toString()),
              const SizedBox(width: 10),
              Text(profile.type.name.toString()),
            ],
          )
        );
```

In schema.graphql

```
type Profile @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  rating: Float
  comment: String
  type: Type @connection
}

type Type @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  langCode: String!
}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. When I query from the non-local database, I receive the Model along with it's Children data, but then when it's synced it locally, it no longer gives me child data on sync :/

Comment: Im also confused about this works across cloud and local data

Comment: Please did you ever find a solution to this